# Pass form type to view

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to create a generic view that gets a form type (from forms.py) and render it to html.
I need that different urls will pass different forms. lets say I have form1 and form2 classes in forms.py, I need to pass the form to **urlpatterns**, something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^form_test1/$', views.generic_form, name='form_test', form_type = forms.form1()),
    url(r'^form_test2/$', views.generic_form, name='form_test2', form_type = forms.form2()),
]
```

Is it can be made? and if not, how can I achieve the required generics.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in fact use the third positional parameter to `url()` as a dict of extra arguments to pass to the view:

```
url(r'^form_test1/$', views.generic_form, {'form_type': forms.form1}, name='form_test'),
```

Note that you should pass the class, not an instance, to the view; and remember the view needs to accept `form_type` as an argument.

However I would really say this is the wrong way to do it. Things like this belong in the view itself. Instead, capture an argument and do the logic in the view:

```
url(r'^form_test(?P<form_id>\d+)/$', views.generic_form, name='form_test'),
```

...

```
FORMS = [ forms.form1, forms.form2 ]

def generic_form(request, form_id):
    FormClass = FORMS[form_id]
```

or use a dictionary and whatever naming scheme makes sense.